# How to update a list of documents in Firestore ONLY if the entire list is completed

Tags: database, firebase, dart, asynchronous, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to add a list of objects to firestore, but only update the objects in Firestore if the entire list is finished updating. For example, if my app crashes, the user closes it, or the phone turns off prior to the cloud sync finishing, I want all updates to be either scrapped or finished, but not mixed.

I am currently just adding the objects like shown in '***updateObjectDataReset***' below (iterative list creation not shown). The problem is that if the user closes the app prior to finish, the database is left with both old and newly updated objects, rather than all old or all newly updated objects. This corrupts the app.

```
 var object = await Object(
        value1: value1,
        value2: value2,
        docId: doc.docId ?? '',
  );

  await list.add(object);

  Future<void> updateObjectDataReset(List<Object> list) async {
    for (var doc in list) {
    var value1 = doc.value1;
    var value2 = doc.value2;
    var docid = doc.docId;
    var user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    var uid = user.uid;
    try {
        await vaultCollection.doc(uid2).collection('vault').doc(docid
        ).update({
          'value1': value1,
          'value2': value2,
        });
    } catch (err) {
    }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Have you had a look at [batched writes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes)?

Comment: Awesome I'll check this out. Thank you. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions